# set default python version when run the program as executable ./xxx.py - on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.x

I would like to run the python directly as executable file like `./xxx.py`

However, when I run it like this, it will automatically use python 2.7 instead of python 3.

How could I use python 3 to run the executable python file?

In the case:

```
./magane.py shell
```

It will give me

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

But I would like to have this:

```
python3 manage.py shell
/home/cliu/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:57: RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2015-05-31 15:24:46.785297) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

where python3 uses ipython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tell python what version to use and to make it executable on Linux you have to do the following steps:

Add `#!` to the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Add permissions to run it

```
chmod +x xxx.py
```

Answer (score 2):

As the first line of our script you may use :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

In this way you can add this line to the scripts which are written to be ran on Python3 and ignore otherwise.